# Kubectl: error: proto: mismatching end group marker

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kind

I am using Kind, and I was trying to create a user. Please check the below commands:-

```
openssl genrsa -out utk.key 2048
openssl req -new -key utk.key -out utk.csr
```

Then I create a yaml file:- create_user.yaml

```
apiVersion: certificates.k8s.io/v1
kind: CertificateSigningRequest
metadata: 
  name: utk
spec: 
  request: 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
  signerName: kubernetes.io/kube-apiserver-client
  usages: 
    - client auth
```

`kubectl apply -f create_user.yaml`

But I am getting Proto error. What is this error? Why I am getting this?

`error: proto: mismatching end group marker`

What am I doing wrong? If anyone can help, would be great.

Comment: Can you confirm your request is matching output of this command `cat utk.csr|base64|tr -d '\n'`

Comment: Hi I just edited, but the results are always same @P....

Comment: Try doing `dos2unix` over your file

Comment: did you figure out the answer ?

Comment: I'm also facing same error, unable to find anything related to it

Answer (score 0):

well, i just met the same problems. It is because i misuse the role to do that . Firstly , install kubernetes with root;Secondly, use sudo add kubernetes environments : mkdir -p $HOME/.kube, balabala...; then ,you can apply successfully.

Comment: please elaborate your answer.

Comment: 1 > use root  ` kubeadm init \  --kubernetes-version=v1.20.0 --pod-network-cidr=10.24.0.0/16 `
2> mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
3>  sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
4>  sudo chow $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
then you can use your account which is not root, and then i solved this  problem.